# Using generics to produce a IEnumerable for generic type

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable

I've got a class X, Y and Z and need a way to have one method to return an IEnumerable of X, Y or Z, something like :

```
public IEnumerable<T> BuildList<T>(String sql)
{
    return Query<T>(sql);
}
```

Where Query is a custom method to do SQL queries and mapping the result to a IEnumerable of T.

I want to use it like :

```
var x_items = BuildList<X>("select * from table_x");
var y_items = BuildList<Y>("select * from table_y");
var z_items = BuildList<Z>("select * from table_z");
```

Is the problem the Query-method or I'm I just doing the generics wrong?

Comment: Well that *looks* okay - what error are you getting? What benefit is this really providing over calling just `Query`? You haven't really provided enough information for us to help you...

Comment: The info is thin, I know - sorry. I cannot call Query-directly cuz' it's located in a data access layer. Errors I'm getting: 'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TStorage' in the generic type or method 'Data.SQL.SqlDataAccessLayerBase.Query<TStorage>(string, params Data.SQL.SqlParameter[])' and error #2 "The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TStorage' in the generic type or method 'Data.SQL.SqlDataAccessLayerBase.Query<TStorage>(string, params Data.SQL.SqlParameter[])'". Does that help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the compiler error you've given in the comment, it sounds like you just need a type constraint on `T`:

```
public IEnumerable<T> BuildList<T>(String sql) where T : class, new()
{
    return Query<T>(sql);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

type of T should be exist in dbcontext

Comment: What do you mean by “exist”? Anyway, this is probably not the problem.

Comment: i think the question is vague,but in EF the when we quering by Query<T> the type of T should be known ,shouldent be?

Comment: The type *is* known, it’s either `X`, `Y` or `Z`.